# how to inject a Map object by guice?

Tags: java, collections, guice, inject

```
class Person{
  Map sons;
  Map getSons(){
    return sons;
  }
}

class Test{
  public void Main(){
    Person p=new Person();
    Map sons=new HashMap<String,Person>();
    sons.add("jack",new Person());
    .....  // here use guice to inject this Map object to p,how to do it?
    System.out.print(new Person().getSons().count());
  }
}
```

just like the code showed about,how to inject a existing Map object into a bean by guice ?

Comment: You use row type on `Person` field `Map sons`, don't you?

Comment: generic class of course!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to use a [TypeLiteral](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html)

You will then need to use [this bind method](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#bind%28com.google.inject.TypeLiteral%3CT%3E%29).

Another option would be to wrap up your Map in a simpler type, a `PersonAccess`, perhaps. This might be better anyway since it could hide the implementation of the lookup.